# Creating an object only the first time in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm making an app where a user makes a safe by going to /mysafe. But i only want to create it the first time when he goes there and for the next time when he goes to /mysafe it should redirect to /mysafe/theidofit.

See my app.js

```html
app.get('/mysafe',async (req,res)=> {
    const safe=new Safe()
    safe.author=req.user._id
    safe.save()
    res.redirect(`/mysafe/${safe._id}`)
})
```

I tried adding a middleware  but in my user schema i dont have a safe defined.Do i need to define it or can i do it without it?

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }   
});
```

Comment: are you using mongoose by any chance?

Comment: yes im using mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/mysafe', async (req,res)=> {
  let safe = await Safe.findOne({author: req.user._id});
  if (!safe) {
    safe = new Safe()
    safe.author=req.user._id
    safe.save()
  }
  res.redirect(`/mysafe/${safe._id}`)
})
```